# Email alerts for existing list list items

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-online, email, list-item

I run a SharePoint Online site that my company uses for staffing. There is a List for Positions. Each position gets a status of open when it's first created and remains opened until it is filled. I'm looking to create a workflow that emails certain people once a week about positions that are still open. Is this possible and how would I do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: There's a pause until date action you can use.  You'll have to manually start the workflow on existing items though.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the workflow to all open positions and not just individual ones?

Comment: You might be able to use a site workflow, but I'm not 100% sure.